# Is there a way for an application to determine the original source of an input?

Tags: java, python, windows

Let's say I wrote simple Python application that can assign macros to any standard keyboard press. For example, it can make the "z" key input "hello" into (and because I'm asking specifically about a java app) a java app. Or another example, Windows MouseKeys. MouseKeys (at least superficially) categorically changes the + sign on the num pad into a left mouse click. The Java app will then only receive a left mouse click on a num pad + press and *not*, additionally, the + keystroke, right? In anticipation of a succinct "it depends" response, an explanation at the very least specifically on the mechanics of MouseKeys and gaming mice software that can emulate any key via a button that isn't by default recognized itself by Windows.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Are you trying to input python and get out java? Please be more clear. Also, if you do find a way to do that, why do you want to output different values from different keys?